# не работает keybd_event в цикле for

Tags: c++

Есть цикл for с внутри вложенными командами keybd_event , должны работать , но не делают этого. Как исправить и что не так ?

P.S. извините за ломаный английский.

Код:

```cpp
            cout << "settings to the click:" << endl;
            cout << "print Sleep time" << endl;
            cin >> n;
            cout << "print number clicks" << endl;
            cin >> i;
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
                cout << "print name "<< j <<" button (CapsLook active)" << endl;
                cin >> button[j];
            }
            WinExec( "C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe", 1);
            for(int j=0; j>i; j++){
                Sleep(n);
                keybd_event( button[j] , 0,0,0);
                keybd_event( button[j] , 0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
            }
```

переменные и библиотеки:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>



using namespace std;

string str;
int i, n;

char button[200];
```

Comment: А Вы во втором цикле не перепутали знак сравнения? Там точно **j>i**?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов , да , вы правы , ошибка . спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решено. Был перепутан знак сравнения во втором цикле. Спасибо @ЮрийКозлов